# DJANGO Callback function inside views

Tags: python, django, callback, decorator

What I need is to automatically call a function (callback function) inside one or more views, get its result and pass it to the template.

Here's a simplified example:

utils.py:

```
def getSContent():  
    return 'some dynamic data'
```

views.py:

```
def myFirstView(request):
    ...py code...

    sData = getSContent() <== this line
    return render_to_response('template.html',
                               {'sData': sData, <== this line 
                               ...
                               },
                               contenxt_instance = RequestContext(request))

def mySecondView(request):
    ...py code...

    sData = getSContent() <== this line
    return render_to_response('template.html',
                               {'sData': sData, <== this line 
                               ...
                               },
                               contenxt_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

..and so on.

`sData = getSContent()` and `{'sData': sData}` are repeated inside all these view functions.

- Is there any shortcut for this?
- Can I somehow bind this function to
  specific views of my app without having to specify it (the marked
  lines) all the time?
- Can a decorator do this job?

Keep in mind that I need to catch the function's return and pass it further to the template.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS) setting for this

It's a list of callables (functions). Each function receives `request` as an argument and should return a `dict`, in your case - `return {'sData': getSContent()}`

Comment: Ah, I forgot about context processors! I'll give it a try and come back with a conclusion.  Thanks!

Comment: The simplest solution I found so far, as Igor already specified, is using TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS as follows:   

Define a custom template processor,  

    def custom_proc(request):  
        return {  
            'sData': getSContent(),  
        }  

and use it in the **render_to_response** function,  

    return render_to_response('template.html',  
                             {..whatever..},  
                             context_instance =   RequestContext(request, processors = [custom_proc]  

I just tested it and it works as expected.  

T.